# Google tag manager puts text inside webpage

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

On my site, when you click a button, it looks like Google tag maneger puts this on the end of the page

```
window.lintrk('track', { conversion_id: #### });
```

Anyone an idea how i can disable this?